# Append element in tag right before contents with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

I'll illustrate with an example: I need to convert the following html with javascript

```
<a>Text 1</a>
<a>Text 2</a>
<a>Text 3</a>
...
```

to code

```
<a><input/>Text 1</a>
<a><input/>Text 2</a>
<a><input/>Text 3</a>
...
```

I don't have a clue how to achieve that with createElement, appendChild or insertBefore/After.

Comment: is jQuery an option for you? also that wouldn't actually be valid html an input in a href..

Comment: possible duplicate [How can I implement prepend and append with regular Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391576/how-can-i-implement-prepend-and-append-with-regular-javascript)

Comment: Treat it as a string. Grab the HTML, use .replace(), insert it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### .insertBefore, and .firstChild

You could insert your new input element before the first child of each anchor:

```
// Gather up a reference to all anchors
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), inputEl;
// Cycle over all of them
for ( var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++ ) {
  // Create a new input field
  inputEl = document.createElement("input");
  // Insert it before the first child of the anchor
  anchors[i].insertBefore( inputEl, anchors[i].firstChild );
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ibugul/edit#javascript,html

#### Regular Expression

Or you could use the `replace` method:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), 
    c = a.length;

while ( c-- ) {
  a[c].innerHTML = a[c].innerHTML.replace( /(.*)/, function( s, c2 ){
    return "<input />" + c2;
  }); 
}
```

#### Modify .innerHTML

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), 
    c = a.length;

while ( c-- ) a[c].innerHTML = "<input />" + a[c].innerHTML;
```

#### jQuery

If you're already using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) on your site, you could use that to make this even shorter:

```
$("a").prepend("<input />");
```

Note, it is not worth including the library *just* for this.

Comment: I know, with jQuery it's simple but I don't need it this time.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that hard :)

```
​(function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
        input,
        i = links.length;

    while (i--) {
        input = document.createElement("input");
        links[i].insertBefore(input, links[i].firstChild);
    }
}())​
```