# Prepending a SPAN element inside all paragraphs with React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

Could anyone help me with this problem?

I have an HTML document with a bunch of paragraphs elements inside it and I'd like to put a  element at its beginning. The content was created by the user, using a WYSIWYG editor for instance.

E.g:

```
<p>Some text was written here</p>
<p>and here</p>
<p>and here</p>
```

should become:

```
<p><span></span>Some text was written here</p>
<p><span></span>and here</p>
<p><span></span>and here</p>
```

Is there a way to do such thing with **ReactJS** since I can't modify directly the DOM ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append element in tag right before contents with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657487/append-element-in-tag-right-before-contents-with-javascript)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a valid use case for React, and even if React could do this you're better off using native JavaScript:
`const pTags = document.querySelectorAll('p');`
`for (let i = 0; i < pTags.length - 1; i++) {
   pTags[i].prepend(document.createElement('span'));
}`

Comment: ReactJs advices against the manipulation of DOM outside of it scope. this would prevent react from keeping track of the DOM tree and hence updating it correctly

Answer (score 1):

First let assume the prop which holds the paragraph is `content`.

Before rendering content you need parse it and alter it as a `String`, to do that add this method to you component

```
AddLeadingSpan( content ){

    // pattern for the openeing P tag
    const targetEl = /<p>/gi;

    // substitute for the matching result
    const subsEl = "<p><span>im a span tag </span>"; // add some text for relevance

    // simply use the native string API to do the replacement
    return content.replace( targetEl, subsEl);
}
```

the above method shouldn't be called directly from the render function due to the fact that it returns a `string` which will be printed as a `string`.

To solve that problem we need another method (which in this case will act as a middleware ) :

```
renderAsHTML( content ){
    return(
      {__html:this.AddLeadingSpan( content ) }
    )
}
```

Finally let go to the render method:

```
 render(){
     return(
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.renderAsHTML( this.props.content )}>
         </div>
     )
 }
```

You need to invoke the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to do things the React way, for more info check [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), but you need to sanitize content to prevent against [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)