# Add new Row before first row in java script

Tags: javascript, dom

Hi I have code as follows:

```
function addRowToTable(num){
if (hasLoaded) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById(TABLE_NAME);
    var nextRow = tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length;
    var iteration = nextRow + ROW_BASE;
    if (num == null) {
        num = nextRow;
    } else {
        iteration = num + ROW_BASE;
    }

    // add the row
    var row = tbl.tBodies[0].insertRow(num);

    // cell
    var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
    var LNInpT = document.createElement('input');
    LNInpT.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            LNInpT.setAttribute('value', 'name');
            cell0.appendChild(LNInpT);

    // Pass in the elements you want to reference later
    // Store the myRow object in each row
    row.myRow = new myRowObject(textNode, txtInp, cbEl, raEl);
}}
```

---

Please help me to Add new Row before first row in table with editing this code.
tanks

Comment: Have you considered to use $('#myTable tr:first').before('<tr>...</tr>');?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
var tbody = myTable.tbodies[0];
var tr = tbody.insertRow(-1); // puts it at the start

var td = document.createElement('td');
td.innerHTML = "Something";
tr.appendChild(td);
```

Comment: According to documentation of insertRow function. You should use 0 instead of -1 to add row as first row of the table. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use jQuery which will make this much easier (with the [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method). If you can't or don't want to, you should be able to use [insertBefore](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_insertbefore.asp).

You might want to look at this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391576/how-can-i-implement-prepend-and-append-with-regular-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method for that.