# javascript: how to append div in "begining" of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a div and i want to append another div inside it. but, by using `appendChild()` it always insert DOM element in end of container element.but i want to insert it in *starting* of container `div`.
How to achieve this ?

```
var newDiv= document.createElement('div');
newDiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text'/>";
var item = document.getElementById('containerDivId');
item.appendChild(newDiv);`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391576/how-can-i-implement-prepend-and-append-with-regular-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> use 'item.insertBefore(newDiv, item.firstChild);'

Answer (score 8):

[`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) is what u need..

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
 item.prepend(newDiv);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you've included `jquery` tag... You can use `prepend()` method.

Or you could use pure JS `insertBefore`:

```
item.insertBefore(newDiv, item.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use prepend function in jQuery. For example,

```
$(item).prepend(newDiv);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you find [insertBefore](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727).

```
parentElem.insertBefore(insertedElem, parentElem.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use prepend() on the parent element to add a child first.

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

I don't have time to test it, but i think that will work.

```
var newDiv= document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text'/>";
var item = document.getElementById('containerDivId');
    item.prepend(newDiv);
```

Comment: Oh god, so many answers, sorry. Was empty when i started writing =)

Comment: As edited by Ajay, this works without jquery but i don't know how it reacts when the container has no children? And fyi, he tagged the question with jquery so the answer before the edit was valid as well.

Comment: I rolled back the answer to the original version, Ajay's edit was invalid (it changed too much, and was rather a comment)

Comment: The code you posted is incorrect. `item` is a DOM element and does not have a method `.prepend`.