# Adding a new row above the first row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a table with 12 columns. Each column would have a text box. `When I click on an 'Add' button, a new row should be inserted above the first row of the table`. How would I do it? Say, if I use jquery append(), it would only add the row at the end but I want to add at the top of the first row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript: how to append div in "begining" of another div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110484/javascript-how-to-append-div-in-begining-of-another-div)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
$("#tableId tbody").prepend("<tr>..</tr>");
```

Answer (score 3):

In [Vanilla JavaScript](http://vanilla-js.com/), it really is as simple as:

```
var firstRow = yourTable.rows[0];
firstRow.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow,firstRow);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following alternatives for that

1) **.before()**  for documentations [click here](http://api.jquery.com/before/)
2) **.insertBefore()** for documentations [click here](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)
3) **.prepend()** for documentations [click here](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [.prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$("#tableId tbody").prepend("tr code here");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$('table > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr>...</tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.prepend()` method. This function do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table id="tblTest">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Add" id="btnAdd"></input></td>
    </tr>
</table>


var row = $("#tblTest tbody").html();
$("#btnAdd").click(function(){
    $("#tblTest tbody").prepend(row);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekjain/bpnM3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In Vanilla JavaScript, to add a new row at the top of a table is as simple as:

```js
const table = document.getElementById("myTable");

var row = myTable.insertRow(1);  // Give index as 1

var cell1= row.insertCell(0);
var cell2= row.insertCell(1);

cell1.innerHTML = "Contents in cell1";
cell2.innerHTML = "Contents in cell2";
```

Give the index for the `insertRow()` method as `1`.