# Append data within a class using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to append a text within a class using Javascript, not by using jQuery. 
Example:

```
<div class="A">
    <div class ="B">
        <div class="C">
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

After putting text within `Class="B"`, it should look like:

```
<div class="A">
    <div class ="B">
         This is text
        <div class="C">
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

I want to do it without using jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Lookup the `prependChild` and `appendChild` methods.

Comment: With loads of examples on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391576/how-can-i-implement-prepend-and-append-with-regular-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [**`insertAdjacentHTML()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("B"); // get all elements with class 'B'
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { // for every element with class 'B':
    elements[i].insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "This is text");
    // insert text just inside the element
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
    <div class="B"><!-- Text will be inserted here -->
        <div class="C">
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also do the trick:

```
function prependTextToClassB(){
        var textNode = document.createTextNode('This is text');
        var elB = document.querySelector('.B');
        var elC = document.querySelector('.C');
        elB.insertBefore(textNode, elC);
    }
```