# How can I prepend my HTML to the body instead of appending it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My code so far:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var html = '<style>.alert {padding: 20px;background-color: blue;color: white;}</style><div class="alert">test</div>';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

My problem is that I want to put this Alert BEFORE my current HTML structure. I know append is obviously putting it AFTER, but is there a workaround or some other method to move it so it's before?

EDIT: the implemented iFrame (generated through JS) is disappearing after 1-2 seconds: Reason??

Comment: On top as in overlapping and covering up the other html? Or prepending: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391576/how-can-i-implement-prepend-and-append-with-regular-javascript

Comment: Oh you want to prepend the new `div` to so that it shows up at the top of the html file?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391576/how-can-i-implement-prepend-and-append-with-regular-javascript

Comment: You should try changing the position parameter in your style tag for `.alert`. If you do not set this parameter, the position parameter will be static by default, which means it will try to position itself next to other static elements.

Comment: The amount of misinformation in some of these comments is outstanding.

Comment: I'll see if thats it. (Yes I want to put it before my HTML, not overlapping or anything)

FYI, it's an intranet webpage so adblockers shouldnt be a problem

Comment: So the iframe is on top now, but why is it disappearing after some sec?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to insert the iframe at the beginning of the body, or insert that HTML at the beginning of the iframe (which is empty, so it shouldn't matter).