# How to insert an HTML element in front of others?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to insert a `<br>` in front of all the `<strong>` tags in someone else's website (using the console). I can insert them *after* with this:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('strong')).forEach((x) => x.appendChild(document.createElement('br')))
```

How can I do it before?

Comment: solution possibly here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391576/how-can-i-implement-prepend-and-append-with-regular-javascript

Comment: Did you search insert Before JavaScript? Seems like the first thing I would do....

Comment: Do it with css...