# Appendchild image to top of table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use appendchild to make a button that displays a random image from an array into a table, and will continue to display a new image on each click, but I need the newest image to stick to the top of the column, not the bottom. I tried to do this below but it appears to be an error.

```js
function display_random_image1() {
  var theImages = [{
      src: "https://i.imgur.com/Ej3qKfd.png",
      width: "120",
      height: "120"
    },
    {
      src: "https://i.imgur.com/P1i0O2m.png",
      width: "120",
      height: "120"
    },
    {
      src: "https://i.imgur.com/FRaU0bc.png",
      width: "120",
      height: "120"
    }
  ];

  var preBuffer = [];
  for (var i = 0, j = theImages.length; i < j; i++) {
    preBuffer[i] = new Image();
    preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i].src;
    preBuffer[i].width = theImages[i].width;
    preBuffer[i].height = theImages[i].height;
  }

  // create random image number
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    //  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    imn = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return preBuffer[imn];
  }

  // 0 is first image,   preBuffer.length - 1) is  last image

  var newImage = getRandomInt(0, preBuffer.length - 1);


  // display the image  
  var targetContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
  targetContainer[0].appendChild(newImage);
  targetContainer.insertBefore(newImage, targetContainer.childNodes[0]);
}
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="initial" onclick="display_random_image1();">Beginning R</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="container">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391576/how-can-i-implement-prepend-and-append-with-regular-javascript[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391576/how-can-i-implement-prepend-and-append-with-regular-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your insertBefore statement like below,

```
targetContainer[0].insertBefore(newImage, targetContainer[0].firstChild);
```

Check the below running code,

```js
function display_random_image1() {
 var theImages = [{
   src: "https://i.imgur.com/Ej3qKfd.png",
   width: "120",
   height: "120"
  },
  {
   src: "https://i.imgur.com/P1i0O2m.png",
   width: "120",
   height: "120"
  },
  {
   src: "https://i.imgur.com/FRaU0bc.png",
   width: "120",
   height: "120"
  }
 ];

 var preBuffer = [];
 for (var i = 0, j = theImages.length; i < j; i++) {
  preBuffer[i] = new Image();
  preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i].src;
  preBuffer[i].width = theImages[i].width;
  preBuffer[i].height = theImages[i].height;
 }

 function getRandomInt(min, max) { // create random image number
  imn = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return preBuffer[imn];
 }

 var newImage = getRandomInt(0, preBuffer.length - 1); // 0 is first image,   preBuffer.length - 1) is  last image

 var targetContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("container"); // display the image  
 targetContainer[0].insertBefore(newImage, targetContainer[0].firstChild);
}
```

```css
th, td { border: 1px solid black; width: 100px }
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button id="initial" onclick="display_random_image1();">Beginning R</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="container">
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the new image to stick at the top, use [ParentNode.prepend()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) instead.

```
...
// display the image  
  var targetContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
  // targetContainer[0].appendChild(newImage);
  // targetContainer.insertBefore(newImage, targetContainer.childNodes[0]);
  targetContainer[0].prepend(newImage);
```